# Avoid duplicate records in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new in ASP.NET so I have problem with duplicate records in my search enginee. When I search for the towns, some records are duplicate some of them are tree-douple.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

**Controller.cs**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Attorney")]
public ActionResult CreateNext(int? id)
{
    var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var nfDoc = db.NFDOCUMENTS.Find(id);


    if (nfDoc.UserId == currentUser.Id && nfDoc.FacilityId == null)
    {
        var contacts = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility");
        List<string> towns = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in contacts)
        {
            if (!towns.Contains(item.City))
            {
                towns.Add(item.City);  


            }
        }



        ViewData["towns"] = towns;


        var medProviders = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility" && x.Firstname != null).ToList();
        ViewData["medProviders"] = medProviders;

        var pat = db.Patients.Where(x => x.Id == nfDoc.PatientId).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.Address = pat.Address1 + ", " + pat.City + ", " + pat.State + ", " + pat.Zip;
        ViewBag.InsuranceId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Insurance Carrier"), "Id", "Firstname");
        ViewBag.AdjusterId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Adjuster"), "Id", "Firstname");
        ViewBag.FacilityId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility"), "Id", "Firstname");
        ViewBag.DoctorId = new SelectList(db.Contacts.Where(s => s.ContactCategory.Name == "Doctor"), "Id", "Firstname");

        ViewBag.PatientId = pat.Id;
        ViewBag.PatientName = pat.Firstname + " " + pat.Lastname;

        return View();
    }

    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
}
```

**View**

SO I expect after searchin engine filted towns, I want to avoid duplicates

```
  <div class="input-group col-md-12">
   <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search towns" />
   </div>
<ul class="list-group nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="height: 200px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto">
<li><a class="reload-towns"><i class="icon-location4"></i> ALL TOWNS</a></li>
  @foreach (var item in towns)
  {
 <li><a class="town" data-town="@item"><i class="icon-location3"></i> @item</a></li>
}
    </ul>
          </div>
                 </div>
                       </div>
```

Comment: ASP.NET is a *web* framework. It has nothing to do with data access. Most likely you want to ask about *Entity Framework*. You'll have to post the *relevant* code and explain what's wrong. What duplicates are you talking about? Which queries? What does the table contain, what did you expect, what did you get?

Comment: Btw if you load towns from your *Contacts* table, you'll always have at least two contacts from the same town.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my questions. SO I am looking for towns, after I filter towns, I get duplicate ones. I want to avoid that

Comment: If you want to select distinct items, use `.Select()` to select what you want and `.Distinct()` to select only distinct entries. You don't need to fill lists manually either, just call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`

Comment: I'll repeat it, ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with data access. The view code doesn't explain anything. The code that loads towns though is rather inefficient and probably wrong

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I dont understand what you mean ? 
I call 
towns..Distinct() but I get NullPointException

Comment: Not in the code you posted. You didn't provide any data samples either, or what the results look like. Views have *nothing* to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: You have the images above. Check it

Comment: those have nothing to do with the data. You *don't* need to post images to show the results of a query. Those images don't show what the data look like at all, whether the casing is wrong, whether there are extra spaces after a string.

Comment: What kind of data do you need to solve this error ? 
I posted the function where the main problem is. Do you need to post full my project here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET is a web framework. It has nothing to do with data access. Data access is the job of *Entity Framework*.

You don't explain which query returns duplicates, but I suspect that you have *more* than one contact per city. This loop :

```
    foreach (var item in contacts)
    {
        if (!towns.Contains(item.City))
        {
            towns.Add(item.City);  
        }
    }
```

uses .NET comparison rules which means casing and whitespace matters.

It could be rewritten as

```
var towns=db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility")
                     .Select(x=>x.City)
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

This will generate a query that would look like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT City
FROM Contacts inner join ContactCategory on ContactCategory.ID=Contacts.CategoryID
Where ContactCategory.Name='Facility';
```

This will only unique city names and returns the result in a list. Whether the string's case matters depends on the `City` column's collation but the most common option is to use case-insensitive collations.

This could still fail if the `City` column contains dirty data, eg with leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: This looks like the best way to do it!

Comment: Both of the solution works fine for me :) 
Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix this on the c# side you can always use HashSet (hashset collection add another string to collection only when it's not duplicated).

So instead of using this:

```
List<string> towns = new List<string>();
```

Use:

```
HashSet<string> towns = new HashSet<string>();
```

From my point of view it's better to solve this problem on SQL side (entity framework):

```
var towns = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility").Select(m => m.City).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I get error when I use HasSet<>
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Dennix you just doing something wrong. As I sad in post the best way is to use entity framework to get distinct values, but if you're interested how to do it on the c# side and how to use HashSet collection just show me how you tried to use this hashset and I will try to fix it ;)

Comment: Ok, just to check solution how does it work :) 
If I get any error I will write it here :) 
Thank you :)